# Translation Golf XXII - The Neverending Story

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

Finished the game has. [The winner Charlie is](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22752/13628).

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This edition's proposed text is a fragment from the book *The Neverending Story* by Michael Ende.
In it, Atreyu, one of the main characters, gets advice about the power of AURYN (a magical medallion); and about how said power relates to the power of the Childlike Empress, the little girl who also happens to be the ruler of the whole world of Fantastica.

> AURYN gives you great power … but you must not make use of it. For the Childlike Empress herself never makes use of her power. AURYN will protect you and guide you, but whatever comes your way you must never interfere, because from this moment on your own opinion ceases to count. For that same reason you must go unarmed. You must let what happens happen. Everything must be equal in your eyes, good and evil, beautiful and ugly, foolish and wise, just as it is in the eyes of the Childlike Empress. You may only search and inquire, never judge. Always remember that, Atreyu!
>
> <sub>(455 letters)</sub>

Example, non-golfed, translation:

> AURYN te da un gran poder... pero no debes hacer uso del mismo. Porque la propia Emperatriz Infantil nunca hace uso de su poder. AURYN te protegerá y te guiará, pero ante lo que sea que te encuentres en tu camino nunca debes interferir, porque desde este mismo momento tu opinión deja de importar. Por esa misma razón debes ir desarmado. Debes dejar que ocurra lo que sea que ocurra. Todo debe ser igual a tus ojos, bueno y malvado, bello y feo, insensato y sabio, tal como lo es a ojos de la Emperatriz Infantil. Solo has de buscar y preguntar, nunca juzgar. ¡Recuerda siempre eso, Atreyu!
>  
>  <sub>(463 letters)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters?
Join us in [Translation-Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf), our game-specific chat room, or in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### <strike>326 293 232 209 187</strike> 159 caracteres

> Poder, escudo y guía AURYN es. ¿Usarlo? Ni la Reina Niña lo usa. Ella todo igual lo ve: bien, mal; bellos, feos; sabios, bobos. Sin armas ve; busca, aborda, no juzgues; lo que sea, será: nada cambies. ¡Recuerda, Atreyu!

[image: Yoda]

- [Abordar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=08ht72h): Acercarse a alguien para hacerle una pregunta, iniciar un diálogo o tratar algún asunto.
- Según el Merriam-Webster, la palabra "childlike" hace referencia a que "parece, sugiere o que es apropiado para un niño", pero no que lo sea. También propone que se usa para personas "marcadas por la inocencia y la ingenuidad". Así que cambio "infantil" por "[niña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=08ht72h)", que tiene una acepción que dice "dicho de una persona que no es un niño: que obra con poca reflexión o con ingenuidad".
- Al final se dice "no juzgues". "[Juzgar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MfZSHIu)" aquí significa "formar opinión sobre algo o alguien" (acepción 3), luego la frase "tu opinión no vale ya" queda redundante y se elimina.

Comment: ¿A nadie le parece mal cambiarle el nombre a la Emperatriz Infantil? Entiendo que es un nombre traducible, a Peter cuando se lo dije contó que no conocía el libro y sólo traducía, es excusable eso pero conociéndolo se me hace muy raro. ¿Cambiaríais por ejemplo "La Estrella de la Muerte" por "El Astro de la Parca" o algo así?

Comment: @blonfu obviamente ha sido duro cambiarle el nombre, pero al menos lo he justificado. ¡Todo sea por el translation-golf! :-)

Comment: No había leído tu explicación, lo decía no solo por la tuya sino por la de @walen también aunque fuera de concurso y alguna otra que ha puesto *reina*. No es lo mismo emperatriz que reina. Supongo que vale para el juego pero no me gusta y lo digo ;)

Comment: No había visto eso O_O. Touché. Vale, me rindo.

Comment: Sí, sí. Nada en las reglas dice lo contrario. Yo voy a mantener el nombre, he hecho golfeos en otros juegos demasiado radicales pero ahora creo que prefiero autoimponerme algunos límites

Answer (score 4):

## 334 caracteres

> Auryn da un gran poder que no debes usar. Ni la Emperatriz Infantil lo hace. Auryn guía y protege, pero no interfieras en lo que los hados te traen, pues tu opinión no importa, y deja que las cosas sucedan. Por eso has de ir desarmado. Todo debe ser igual a tus ojos, bueno y malvado, bello y feo, insensato y sabio, tal como lo es a ojos de la Emperatriz Infantil. Busca y pregunta, mas nunca juzgues. ¡Recuérdalo siempre, Atreyu!

Answer (score 4):

### <s>248</s> 224 Caracteres

> Auryn te da mucho poder... guardalo. La Reina Niña no lo usa. Auryn te guía y cuida, no cambiés lo que te pase, tu opinión no vale en ese instante. Ve sin armas, que ocurra todo, neutro ante bien o mal, bello o feo, tonto o sagaz, como la Reina Niña. Podés escudriñar, sin juzgar. ¡Acordate Atreyu!

Vamos a vosear para mermar los 225... (y creo que algunos lanzarán la carta de menos de 200 caracteres mientras duermo...)

- El poder, si no se usa... guardémoslo (para botarlo, creo que tendría que usarlo sobre algo...)
- Es mejor ir sin armas que desarmado (1 caracter)
- Atreyu debe dejar que cualquier cosa ocurra
- El significado de [Escudriñar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GMDQp1e), da a entender que investiga y pregunta

Cualquier otra duda, bienvenida... en caso de copia involuntaria (vi caracteres, 
no textos) ya veré como arreglo el texto

Answer (score 4):

### <s>271 268 233 226 216 184</s> 166 caracteres

> AURYN  te cuida, guía y da poder. La Emperatriz Infantil no usa el
> suyo, no juzga bueno, bello, necio y sus opuestos, haz igual. Que
> venga lo que deba, tu juicio no vale, así irás inerme. Busca e indaga.
> ¡Retenlo, Atreyu!

**venir:** Suceder, acontecer o sobrevenir.

**inerme:** Que está sin armas (tal vez os suene de otro TG ;))

**deja venir lo que deba:** Aquí resumos dos frases, por un lado *deja venir* quiere decir que no se intervenga en las cosas y añadiendo *lo que deba* me refiero a que pase lo que tenga que pasar.

**retener:** Conservar en la memoria algo.

Comment: Pues precisamente he puesto *o* queriendo decir que si interfiere en los sucesos su juicio (opinión) no tendrá valor, si no interfiere todo bien. Así lo entiendo yo al menos.

Comment: ah vale, lo había entendido mal

Answer (score 3):

### <strike>252</strike> 249 caracteres

> ÁURYN le da gran poder no para usarlo, pues ni la Niña Emperatriz lo usa. Amparo y guía le será ÁURYN, mas no se meta en lo que vea pues sus ideas ya no valen. Por eso irá sin armas, dejará suceder. Tal como a ella, le será todo igual, bien y mal, bonito y feo, necio y sabio. Podrá averiguar pero no juzgar. ¡Recuérdelo, Atreyu!

Tratar de usted me ahorra 5 caracteres.

En la versión original combinaba las primeras dos frases de forma que eliminaba el sujeto de la segunda, y la empleaba en vez el sujeto original de la tercera frase. Sin embargo, después de leer un comentario de blonfu me parecía conveniente leer [la página de Wikipedia del cuento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_historia_interminable), y me di cuenta de que me había engañado el pasaje citado pues ÁURYN y la Emperatriz no son sinónimos. La traducción *Niña Emperatriz* viene de esa página de Wikipedia. Me gustaría prescindir de la segunda *ÁURYN*, pero sin sujeto explícito sería demasiado ambiguo.

*Serle amparo* traduce *protect*: mi primera idea era *serle aegis* pero para mi sorpresa no lo encuentro en el DRAE. Es una palabra clásica que se utiliza tal cual en inglés.

*Whatever comes your way* sería más estrictamente *lo con que se tope*, pero toparse con algo en el camino es más o menos lo mismo que sentirlo, y no me parece extravagante usar el sentido más relevante (la vista) como metónimo.

*Meterse* es en el sentido 26 del DRAE: *Censurar o criticar algo o a alguien*. Puesto que el pasaje repite la instrucción diciendo "*never judge*", entiendo que ese es el sentido de *interfere*.

*Dejará suceder* igual podría optimizarse a *dejará pasar*, pero las connotaciones de dar paso a los que bajan del bus o del metro son demasiadas fuertes para permitírmelo.

*Search and inquire* me parece una sola acción, la investigación, por lo cual *averiguar*.

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé el nombre de la emperatriz en español siempre se ha traducido como Emperatriz Infantil, queda un poco raro si le cambias el nombre a Emperatriz Ingenua.

Comment: No he leído el libro ni en versión original ni en ninguna traducción, y no hablo alemán así que no me serviría de mucho leerlo en versión original. El diccionario inglés-castellano de Oxford propone como traducciones de *childlike* dos alternativas: *ingenuo* o *de niño*. Si no te gusta, quéjate con walen por pedir una traducción de una traducción...

Comment: No tengo que quejarme a nadie, solo era un comentario ya que para los que conocemos el libro y las películas en español se nos hace raro ver otro nombre distinto. Tampoco hay para tanto solo es una letra más y lo decía para ayudar no para criticar tu traducción.

Comment: Bueno, resulta que hay otra opción aún más corta y respaldada por Wikipedia.

Comment: @walen, convendría editar la pregunta para dejarlo claro porque no se puede dar por sentado más contexto de lo que hay ahí.

Answer (score 3):

```
Fuera de concurso
```

#### 186

> AURYN será guarda y guía, mas no uses su gran poder: la Reina Pueril no lo hace. En lo que pase, no entres: da igual qué opines. Ve sin arma, y que pase. Ve, como ella, todo igual: bien, mal, bello, feo, lelo, sabio. Mira, nunca opines. ¡No olvides, Atreyu!

Comment: Y ahora ya sabemos por qué walen gana todas las ediciones del TG. :-D